# Is it ok to team NIC's from different vendors together in VMware ESX?

Tags: performance, vmware-esx, network-teaming

I want to achieve the best performance with my two servers (SAN and ESX). I have good RAID (LSI,  SASes), that is showing 1GB/s result, so the bottleneck now is network part since I have only two NICs on each port (Intels). I have also 4 Broadcoms.

If I`ll team 2 Intels with 2 Broadcoms on each server, will I achieve 4 Gbps performance?

I know that 10Gb NICs would suit my needs better but I do not have this option right now.

Comment: What protocol are you using to connect to the "SAN"? iSCSI?

Comment: Yes, I`m using iSCSI based SAN

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this works fine in ESX/ESXi - we do it on all our servers.

Just make sure that you realize the implications - you'll loose any features that isn't supported on both the NIC's (like certain type of offloading).

Answer (score 1):

Using bonding in linux this should work flawlessly.
And since ESX is pretty much linux-based, i expect it to work as well.
Not sure about windows though.

Comment: Appreciate your answer. Yes, but my SAN server is Windows based.

Comment: Both of them should use IEEE 802.3ad Link Aggregation Control Protocol (LACP)

Comment: LACP doesn't aggregate bandwidth, just load balances flows (based on MAC or IP) so it's not that useful for NAS setups between two machines. Plus ESX doesn't support LACP.

Comment: ESX is not Linux based. Only the console is based on RHEL or on busybox so that as, mortals, can manage it in a familiar way.

Comment: vmware ESX is Linux-based. Please ignore the nonsense comment above.

Comment: @adaptr please read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware_ESX#Linux_dependencies If ESX was based on Linux they would be forced to release the source code under GPL v2.

Comment: 2 Parts to ESX (note: ESX).  1) The hypervisor 2) The console, which is linux based and there for us users to access the host.  In ESXi (vSphere 5), that Linux console is gone.

Comment: The hypervisor is Linux. You think vmWare coded a friggin OS, kernel, VMM and virtual machine scheduler from scratch ? Show me what process is the hypervisor, if not a kernel process. It's custom - very custom. But runs on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with that is that teaming or bonding does not increase bandwidth **between two stations**.

Teaming can increase the overall bandwidth available to a host and - if LACP or the like is supported - on a switch as well, but the consumers of that bandwidth must be multiple stations/hosts/IPs.

The only way to increase bandwidth between host A and host B using multiple network connections is to... use multiple network connections.

You would have to assign each NIC on each end a separate (virtual) IP and route traffic appropriately.

PS. vmware bonding primarily offers *physical NIC failover*, and connectivity for multiple virtual port groups to the outside in a flexible manner.

Increasing point-to-point bandwidth is not what it does either.

EDITed just in case this wasn't clear: no, connecting 2 systems with multiple NICs in each does NOT increase the bandwidth between them.

Comment: Thanks. Nut ther main question was if the fact that NICs are from different vendors should affect total performance?

Comment: Since all of that is handled by the ESX (Linux) kernel, there is no reason that it should.

Comment: This isn't entirely correct.. I use 4 NIC's for iSCSI and use round-robin MPIO to balance the load across the nic's. You're right in the way that you can't get a single datastream faster than a single path, but remember that you usually run more than 1 VM on a ESX host. You should edit your answer to reflect this.

Comment: pauska: presumably the VM's do not access the storage directly. However using iscsi multipathing (on separate subnets) is a great suggestion.

Comment: May I wonder why "separate subnets" are necessary?

Comment: If you put multiple interfaces on the same subnet your return traffic on the remote box will come back out on the "first" interface on that subnet.